# Fill missing weeks in linq result to 0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I've got this kind of ViewModel, is there a easy way to fill missing weeks so instead of

- Week 17 / 30.000
- Week 25 / 464.000

I've got

- Week 17 / 30.000
- Week 18 / 0
- Week 19 / 0
- ...
- Week 25 / 464.000

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPCnx.png

Comment: You need to add your code to the site as c# formatted text.  Edit your question to enter it between 2 sets of 3 backticks.  Don't put it as an image

Comment: Start with `Enumerable.Range(0, 25)` and then populate data form your source

Answer (score 1):

You have to do left join to database items

```
var dbItems = query.ToList();

var allWeeks = Enumerable.Range(0, 25);

var filledGaps = 
  from w in allWeeks
  join item in dbItems on w equals dbItem.Week into j
  from item in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
  select new ViewModel
  {
     Week = w,
     Value = item?.Value ?? 0
  }
```